# CSS3 Shadow effect not working with zurb foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I want to use [this](http://codepen.io/haibnu/pen/FxGsI) shadow effects in my zurb foundation project. I am trying to apply it to a row class but its not working.

here is the [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BogEoR) to my foundation in codepen

This is the shadow trick I am trying to use

```
.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.row` class in foundation is ment to create a horizontal block to contain vertical columns. In fact it not even visible. In your case you could simply apply the style to the element within the row.

I updated your Pen:

```
http://codepen.io/Robbert89/pen/EVqYXN
```

Hope this helps you!